# Calling methods in dynamically created component angular 2

Tags: angular

I need to add components dynamically from triggered events, i´ve managed to get it working with loadasroot and loadnexttolocation, but the problem is that those only return a promise for the ComponentRef and i cant find a wat to access properties and calling methods in the added components. Ive read some threads about the loadintolocation but it seems that they removed that after releasing the candidate?

Comment: Maybe you could publish some code to show how far you have got, and what you need to do next?

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use the `ComponentResolver` class this way. On the `ComponentRef` instance, you can access both properties and methods of the newly created component.

```
@ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target;

constructor(private resolver: ComponentResolver) {}

createComponent() {
  this.resolver.resolveComponent(MyComp).then(
    (factory:ComponentFactory<any>) => {
      var cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory);
      var cmp = cmpRef.instance;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
then(cmpRef:ComponentRef => {
  cmpRef.instance.myProp = someValue;
  cmpRef.instance.someOutput.subscribe(val => this.someOtherOutput.next(val));
});
```

See also [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468) for the new way `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`.

`DynamicComponentLoader` is deprecated.